# Get column total from list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the sum total of a particular column from a list in a CSV file.  I'm able to select the column and remove the header but I can't add up all of the values.

```
import csv

projectFile = open('data.csv')
projectReader = csv.reader(projectFile)
projectData = list(projectReader)
sum = 0
for amount in projectData[1:]:
    amount = amount[1]
    print(amount)
```

I've tried `sum(amount)` which didn't work and then tried adding a global variable, `sum = 0`, and adding the `float` of the list to it ex: `total= int(sum + float(amount))` and got errors.  I can't use Pandas or mapping for this.

EDIT:

CSV example -

[image]

Comment: Think a minute about how you sum a list manually. One way to do it is to add the next number to the current sum. Can you think how to do this in Python?

Comment: `sum` is a built-in name for a function. Try to avoid shadowing built-in names (it might lead to confusing results later on)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of calculating the sum of the 3rd column from a 3x3 matrix (stored as list of lists). Note that column index of 2 corresponds to the 3rd column:

```
col = 2
my_matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
sum = sum([row[col] for row in my_matrix])
print(sum)
```

The output is:

```
18
```

(calculated as 3+6+9)

**For string matrix** (based on comment by @mpstring)

Just add float() to convert each string to float.

```
col = 2
mymat = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
sum = sum([float(row[col]) for row in mymat])
print(sum)
```

**Given example data.csv** (based on updated question by @mpstring)

```
import csv
projectFile = open('data.csv')
projectReader = csv.reader(projectFile)
next(projectReader)
projectData = list(projectReader)
sum = sum(float(row[1]) for row in projectData)
print(sum)
```

Output is

```
216.61
```

Comment: I think the values in my column are strings currently.  I tried your code and go the error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @mpstring - all you need to do is to add the float() command to convert from string to float. I've added the string example to the answer.

Comment: A small improvement would be to remove the quare brackets so the `sum` is used on a generator instead of actually creating a list first (`sum(row[col] for row in mat)`)

Comment: @maurera I got this error:  sum = sum([float(amount[1]) for amount in projectData])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'amount'

Comment: @mpstring - You haven't told us the contents of data.csv, so we're guessing about what's in there. It sounds like your first row is rownames. You could skip this row by adding the line next(projectReader) after the line projectReader = csv.reader(projectFile)

Comment: @mpstring why did you change it from your original code? You should do: `sum([float(amount[1]) for amount in projectData[1:]])`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I changed it and got this error - ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: @mpstring Then you should also check for empty cells first. This is really hard to help like this. Why don't you post a sample of your csv in the question?

Comment: @Tomerikoo okay, just added it above

Comment: @mpstring - I've edited the answer here that works with your file

Comment: @maurera I'm still getting this:  ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: `sum = sum(...)` smells pretty bad BTW

Comment: (agreed - just keeping with the code from the original question)